# Rails 5 routing to wrong action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I did try several suggestions but I cannot find the way to solve this. My app is working fine but when I try to link_to a custom action it always tries to route to the 'show' action and the result is that parameters don't match (the 'show' action waits for an :id parameter which is assigned the name of the action "id"=>"reporte_asist") so I get an error:

```
Started GET "/equipos/reporte_asist.xls?entrenador=1&final=2017-01-30+00%3A00%3A00+-0600&inicio=2017-01-01+00%3A00%3A00+-0600" for ::1 at 2017-01-10 15:53:09 -0600
**Processing by EquiposController#show as XLS**
  Parameters: {"entrenador"=>"1", "final"=>"2017-01-30 00:00:00 -0600", "inicio"=>"2017-01-01 00:00:00 -0600", "id"=>"reporte_asist"}
  Equipo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "equipos".* FROM "equipos" WHERE "equipos"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Equipo with 'id'=reporte_asist):
```

I tried removing Turbolinks but the problem persists, this is the piece of code that I am using to link to the 'xls' format response:

```
<div data-no-turbolinks>
<%= link_to "Excel", reporte_asist_url(format: "xls", entrenador: @entrenador.id, inicio: @inicio, final: @final, controller: "equipos", action: "reporte_asist")  %>
</div>
```

This is part of my config/routes.rb:

```
resources :categorias
get '/equipos/forma_rep'
post '/equipos/reporte_asist', to: 'equipos#reporte_asist', as: 'reporte_asist'
resources :players
get '/eventos/calendario' => 'eventos#calendario', as: 'calendario'
resources :eventos
get '/equipos/:id/eventos_feed' => 'equipos#eventos_feed', as: 'eventosFeed'
get '/eventos/:id/players_feed' => 'eventos#evento_players', as: 'eventoPlayers'
post '/asistencias', to: 'asistencias#create'
get '/validar/:equipo_id', to: 'players#validar'
resources :equipos
```

This is the rails routes output:

```
  equipos_forma_rep GET    /equipos/forma_rep(.:format)            equipos#forma_rep
      reporte_asist POST   /equipos/reporte_asist(.:format)        equipos#reporte_asist
            players GET    /players(.:format)                      players#index
                    POST   /players(.:format)                      players#create
         new_player GET    /players/new(.:format)                  players#new
        edit_player GET    /players/:id/edit(.:format)             players#edit
             player GET    /players/:id(.:format)                  players#show
                    PATCH  /players/:id(.:format)                  players#update
                    PUT    /players/:id(.:format)                  players#update
                    DELETE /players/:id(.:format)                  players#destroy
         calendario GET    /eventos/calendario(.:format)           eventos#calendario
            eventos GET    /eventos(.:format)                      eventos#index
                    POST   /eventos(.:format)                      eventos#create
         new_evento GET    /eventos/new(.:format)                  eventos#new
        edit_evento GET    /eventos/:id/edit(.:format)             eventos#edit
             evento GET    /eventos/:id(.:format)                  eventos#show
                    PATCH  /eventos/:id(.:format)                  eventos#update
                    PUT    /eventos/:id(.:format)                  eventos#update
                    DELETE /eventos/:id(.:format)                  eventos#destroy
        eventosFeed GET    /equipos/:id/eventos_feed(.:format)     equipos#eventos_feed
      eventoPlayers GET    /eventos/:id/players_feed(.:format)     eventos#evento_players
        asistencias POST   /asistencias(.:format)                  asistencias#create
                    GET    /validar/:equipo_id(.:format)           players#validar
            equipos GET    /equipos(.:format)                      equipos#index
                    POST   /equipos(.:format)                      equipos#create
         new_equipo GET    /equipos/new(.:format)                  equipos#new
        edit_equipo GET    /equipos/:id/edit(.:format)             equipos#edit
             equipo GET    /equipos/:id(.:format)                  equipos#show
                    PATCH  /equipos/:id(.:format)                  equipos#update
                    PUT    /equipos/:id(.:format)                  equipos#update
                    DELETE /equipos/:id(.:format)                  equipos#destroy
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML `<a>` links result in a `GET` request by default. Rails provides a method to create a `POST` request by setting an attribute on the link.

The url helpers generated by your routes, like `reporte_asist`, only generate the correct path/url. They do not pass any additional parameters to `link_to`. If you want to send a `POST` request to the path specified, you need to add a `method: :post` to the options passed to `link_to`:

```
link_to "Excel", reporte_asist_url(...), method: :post
```

That said, it doesn't sound like `POST` is the correct HTTP verb to be using for this action. This sounds like it ought to be a `GET` request.

Note: I truncated parameters passed to `reporte_asist_url` for brevity/clarity; you still need them.

Comment: My logic for using a POST to the report controller action is that I use a GET for the parameter getting form, just like with a CRUD #new action posting to the #create action in the same controller, in this case I am GETting the parameters from the form and PUTting them into the report controller action. It did work fine... thks by the way, I was confused with the parameter grouping with parenthesis.